# mysql script file not executing

Tags: mysql, scripting

I have a few scripts to transfer a db between two mysql servers, this all works great manually.  I am trying to automate the whole process.  I have one script on the source server that just doesn't execute.

When I check the general log I can see it in there, when I load it into workbench it runs no problem.  Again I can see it's entry in the log. I have set the user to login in from any machine, given him every administrative role and schema privilege.

I execute the script the same as my others, in the process of moving the data from one server to the other, this is the only script that runs on the source server the others run on the destination machine.  Both machines are windows os.

```
mysql -usa -p**** -h192.168.0.196 < kissflushforexport.sql
```

the contents of the sql file

```
use kiss;
FLUSH TABLES `additonal_carriage_charge_info_add_ire` 
FOR EXPORT;
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?  Assuming you've a DB `kiss` and table `additonal_carriage_charge_info_add_ire` in kiss with a user with permissions to run `FLUSH`, there should be no error (or output).  Does your script throw an error when you run it?

Comment: a CFG file should be created in the db folder

Comment: sure, you're seeing your data files (.ibd) , your format files (.frm), but not the new .cfg table?

Comment: Also, what version of Mysql are you using?

Comment: Ibd files and frm all there, if I run the command in workbench I have the cfg file until I run the unlock tables command, run the script on command line and nothing happens, version 5.7.15

Comment: 1.) Are you using innodb one file per table setting? 2.) is additonal_carriage_charge_info_add_ire a temp table?

Comment: Finally, are you using the same credentials on workbench as in the script, the `sa` user?

Comment: yes using one file per_table, the table isn't a temp table.  I am using this as an example table.  the script originally handled 450 tables.  Just trying to get one table working in the script, for testing purposes.  yes workbench is using the same credentials.

Comment: Any chance you're out of disk space and can't create a file?

Comment: What do you mean about  `in workbench I have the cfg file until I run the unlock tables command` -- that shouldn't delete any files.  You don't need to explicitly lock anything to run  `flush tables ... for export` the command should acquire locks as needed.

Comment: Try this Hail-Mary: put the `FOR EXPORT` on the same line in the script as the `FLUSH TABLES ...`  You might have some odd EOL character confusing the mysql prompt

Comment: When I run the flush files for export in workbench it creates the CFG file, the cfg file exists until I run the Clear tables command then the CFG file is deleted by mysql.  Just put everything on one line and ran from the command prompt it made no diffeence

Comment: Wow--I'm at a total loss.  I'm going to go out on a limb and predict this is going to be something minor overlooked, like connecting to wrong DB, looking at local or running against a remote db/directory vs. local version...   Good luck!

Comment: I remote desktop to the source server, I have double checked to the ip to the baner at the top of the session, so many times.  Thanks for taking the time.